# how to convert odoo-9 into a new exe file

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I'm trying to compile `odoo-9` source code into a new `.exe file` with custom favicon and name.

Can any one guide me how to achieve it. I want to change the server name and database name as well.

Thank you

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: I want to create a complete new .exe file in a different company name. right from service name and database name. I can also limit the pre installed modules and install as many as times i want to

Comment: well you can have different databases to handle different companies...you can even have two odoo installations in different directories and run them on different ports

Comment: dear danidee am looking for something like creating a new exe with odoo source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odoo .exe file have originally generated by [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Download). First thing you have to do is to extract the exe file with something like [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). In the extracted folder, you will find all the odoo server and service files plus a NSIS script. Now you can add or remove all the modules you want in server folder, make the require changes in NSIS script (you will need some basic knowledge about NSIS language) and recompile it.